# Is there a conprehensive guide on how to take a LED display apart? (ant stuck inside)

Tags: led

The ant is not on the very first layer.

I thought about taking it apart but I haven't been able to find something with a detailed description on how it is done.  [image]

Comment: I'm not helping, but I'm **dying** to know *how* the ant got in there...

Comment: Maybe. But the only comprehensive guides would be model-specific ones, so for example if you had an "Acme View-All-The-Things 9000" monitor, going to google and searching for Acme View-All-The-Things 9000 **teardown**" should help find any guide that exists.

Comment: As @Stephanie said, LCD screen teardowns are often model-specific. If this is a laptop, you might also search for "<laptop model> replace screen", as replacing laptop screens is common and will include full teardown instructions.

Comment: @lornix updated

Comment: @Stephanie updated

Comment: @DarthAndroid updated

Answer (score 3):

I went for it. Had to turn it on in order to find it. The plastic on the top is all scratched from prying.

A picture is worth a thousand words...

[image]

Comment: Where is the **ANT**? **SHOW US!**

Comment: @RogUE It broke apart since it had been there for a couple weeks. I first used a cue tip and then had to go with Windex and a paper towel. It was one of those tiny sugar ants.

Comment: If this was a horror movie, the ant would have laid eggs and in a few weeks, your display would be crawling with them.  You sure are lucky this isn't a horror movie.

Comment: @fixer1234 I would've used a flame thrower to light my Molotov cocktails.